# Fetching data from multiple table

Tags: android, ormlite

I need to get data from two tables in `Android`. I am using `OrmLite` for the database. 
My query is next:

```
SELECT m.*, r.campaign_name, r.description, r.terms_condition 
FROM mycampaignlist m, redeemlanguagedata r 
WHERE r.lang_type = 2
```

How could I create this type of query in `OrmLite`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to get data from two tables in Android... How could I create this type of query in OrmLite.

ORMLite does not support `JOIN` queries using the internal `QueryBuilder` if you are selecting a combination of fields from each table.  In your example, you have some fields from `mycampaignlist` and some from `redeemlanguagedata` so ORMLite can't return a object without more help.

I'd recommend using the [raw queries](http://ormlite.com/docs/raw-queries) functionality and then you can get the output as a `List<String[]>`, `List<Object[]>` if you specify the data-types, or as a list of your own objects if you specify a `RawRowMapper<Foo>`.

For example, to quote from the docs:

```
GenericRawResults<Foo> rawResults = orderDao.queryRaw(
        "SELECT account_id,sum(amount) FROM orders GROUP BY account_id",
    new RawRowMapper<Foo>() {
            public Foo mapRow(String[] columnNames,
              String[] resultColumns) {
                return new Foo(Long.parseLong(resultColumns[0]),
                    Integer.parseInt(resultColumns[1]));
        }
    });
// page through the results
for (Foo foo : rawResults) {
  System.out.println("Account-id " + foo.accountId + " has "
    + foo.totalOrders + " total orders");
}
rawResults.close();
```

Hope this helps.